# storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter with out Parameter ref cursor with Jpa Eclipse Link

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I am new to Jpa i want to execute Procedure

I have Code as Followes

```
private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "todos";
private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("TEST1");
    // set parameters
    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("P_CODE", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("P_DATE", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("P_CURSOR", ResultSet.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR );
    storedProcedure.setParameter("P_CODE", "5110" );
    storedProcedure.setParameter("P_DATE", "01/01/2015" );
    // execute SP
    storedProcedure.execute();
    // get result
    Object obj =storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("tax");

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
```

}

But this is giving an Exception for register out parameter Please tell what we Have to pass 
I am using Jpa EclipseLink Implimentation 
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST1'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored  Error Code: 6550
Call: BEGIN TEST1(P_CODE=>?, P_DATE=>?, P_CURSOR=>?); END;  bind => [3 parameters bound] Query: ResultSetMappingQuery()

Comment: why not post the stored proc, and post the exact exception + stack trace?

Comment: your Store stored Procedure return list , accordingly you change it , i posted answer also

Comment: its Working thank you naresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Store stored Procedure return list, So you do some changes in your code.

**Old Code**

```
 storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("P_CURSOR", ResultSet.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR );

Object obj =storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("tax");
```

**New Code**

```
    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("P_CURSOR",void.class,ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);

Object obj =storedProcedure.getResultList();
```

Your all data store in obj.